# Listview - populate second column with corresponding items from database

Tags: database, vb.net, listview

Fist column of listview is populated from database (database column name KONTO - only values that starts with 2020-), second column of the listview should be populate from corresponding items to KONTO from same database column NAZIV into second column of the listview.

[image]
*Description is in column NAZIV in databsase*

I've been experimenting with this all day and didn't have any success.

Here is the code I have so far :

```
        ListView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
    ListView1.Columns.Add("COL1", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left) 'KONTO
    ListView1.Columns.Add("COL2", 160, HorizontalAlignment.Left) 'NAZIV



    Dim FilePath As String = "W:\GLAVNI\KOR14\"
    Dim DBF_File As String = "MATIKGL"
    Dim ColName As String = "KONTO"
    'Dim naz As String
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
    " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV")
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MATIKGL ORDER BY KONTO, NAZIV", con)
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    While (reader.Read())
                        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(reader("KONTO"))

                        'LOOP BELOW SELECTS ALL ITEMS THAT STARTS WITH 2020-
                        For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                            If ListView1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("2020-") Then

                            Else
                                ListView1.Items.Remove(ListView1.Items(i))
                            End If
                        Next


                    End While

                Else

                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

To be more clear, here is the screen from database.
[image]

Only items starting with 2020- (1) should populate first column of listview, and second column should  be populated with "2020-" description from column NAZIV (2).

Comment: I cant see where you are getting anything from any DB for the 2nd "column".  That said, you need to add subitems to an LV for what will go in the 2,3,4... columns

Comment: I have only two columns in listview. I don't have anything in second column 'cause I don't know how to populate it with corresponding values to first column from database.

Comment: you want to know how to a) get values from the DB or b) add them to a LV as "column" items?

Comment: As you can see from code above I successfully populated first column from the database, let say that there are 500 items in column KONTO in database and only 50 items starting with "2020-", that 50 items populate first column of the listview. **I would like to populate second column of the listview with corresponding items from same database (column NAZIV)** Column NAZIV contains description for KONTO.

Comment: since you are using access, you best bet us to attach the table from one and do a JOIN and get the data all at once, however if you **part** of the column is the key to the other you should consider revising the database so the relationships are easier to define, maintain and use

Comment: @Plutonix I can not do that since database in question (DBF) is in constant use with another (DBASE) application. My VB application is just functional add-in for DBASE application. Can you tell me how to populate second column of a listview and I will experiment with that?

Comment: as in comment #1 - add subitems to an LV item and they will show as columns.  Since this is a DB app, consider using a DataGridView - they are more adept at being a grid and handling data - the LV just **looks** like a grid

Comment: I don't know how to do that. `ListView1.Items(1).SubItems.Add(reader("NAZIV"))` Doesn't work

Comment: 'lv.Items(i).SubItems.Add(rdr.Item("YourColumnName").ToString)` should work.  (the OP code shows NOTHING going on with the subitem, your DB code looks wrong: if KONTO and NAZIV are in the same table dbReader, you need to specify WHAT you want in the LV as I showed and it seems like the related NAZIV should not need to be searched for, but you left a lot out of the post; finally if these are not text columns, you need to convert them using .ToString - the LV doesnt take anything else)

Comment: I've updated my post to be more clear of what I would like to do. The code above is the best that I can do with my knowledge, web and experimentation...and if you could please help me fix it so it can load data into column two of listview. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each LV Item has a collection of SubItems associated with it.  The subItems show as columns in the Details view:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem              ' scratch var for adding items
Dim tmp As String

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MATIKGL ORDER BY KONTO, NAZIV", con)
        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While (reader.Read())

                    ' Db rdr returns Object, cast to string
                    tmp = reader.Item("KONTO").ToString

                    ' no need to loop - just use the scratch vars
                    ' only adding if it contains 2020
                    If tmp.Contains("2020-") Then
                        lvi = New ListViewItem
                        lvi.Text = tmp

                        ' add the sub item
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(reader("NAZIV").toString)
                        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
                    End If
               End While
            End If
        End Using
```

you can get rid of the tmp var using `reader.Item("KONTO").ToString.Contains("2020")`...the above is for clarity

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going insane with this one.